# One to Many Relationship - MySQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I see lot of resources addressing my question, but still I couldn't find a definite solution for this, may be because of lack understanding the concept!

The story here:

Have two tables: 
Products 
prod_id 
prod_name 
cat_fid

Product Categories
cat_id
cat_name

Obviously, cat_fid is the foreign key here to the Categories table. Now the problem:
The product 'Su'n belong to categories - Hot, Round & Star
The product 'Moon' belongs to categories - Cold, Round, Satellite, Planet
The product 'Earth' belongs to categories - Warm, Round, Planet

Now I want to call all the products under Category Round and then Planet or Hot

prod_id        prod_name           cat_fid
1                   Sun                        ??? 
2                   Moon                    ???

cat_id            cat_name
1                    Hot
2                    Cold
3                    Round
4.                   Warm
5                    Planet
6                    Star  ... etc

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you're missing a third table, a Product to Category table.

Seems like you should have a `Product` table with Product_Id and Product_Name, a `Category` table with Category_Id and Category_Name, and then a `Product_Category` table with the Product_Id and Category_Id fields.

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, c.category_id, c.category_name 
from product p
    join product_category pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
    join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id
where c.category_name = 'Round'
```

Comment: OK, Now I have prod_cat table. Then prod_id & cat_id into this. Now the prod_id for sun (1) is having cat_id hot (1). But it's also having cat_id of 3 and  6. So how do I solve this.  Example: ProdID1 = CatID1, ProdID1=CatID2